# convert number into array element and undefined into empty array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

In this Plunker example the following filter is used to make select box options selectable only once
http://plnkr.co/edit/BBqnTlxobUpiYxfhyJuj?p=preview

```
.filter('arrayDiff', function() {
return function(array, diff) {
  console.log(diff);
  var i, item, 
      newArray = [],
      exception = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

  for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    item = array[i];
    if(diff.indexOf(item) < 0 || exception.indexOf(item) >= 0) {
      newArray.push(item);
    }
  }

  return newArray;

};
});
```

I really need such a filter but the problem is that my `diff` variable isn't an array but a number (selected value). (It is 1,2,3 or undefined):
In this code `diff` is either [1](http://plnkr.co/edit/BBqnTlxobUpiYxfhyJuj?p=preview),[2](http://plnkr.co/edit/L9hBa5LapAV76wHrwRnX?p=preview),[3] or [].
How can I rewrite such a filter to work with a number instead of an array.
This is how I use the filter: http://plnkr.co/edit/L9hBa5LapAV76wHrwRnX?p=preview

Comment: Where and how are you using this filter? Please add some code

Comment: Use `===` instead of `indexOf`? Really hard to say without a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: This is how I use it: http://plnkr.co/edit/L9hBa5LapAV76wHrwRnX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
.filter('arrayDiff', function() {
return function(array, diff) {
  console.log(diff);
  var i, item, 
      newArray = [],
      exception = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

  for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    item = array[i];
    if(diff == item || exception.indexOf(item) >= 0) {
      newArray.push(item);
    }
  }

  return newArray;

};
});
```

Comment: It didn't work... You can test it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/L9hBa5LapAV76wHrwRnX?p=preview

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do here

Comment: I want each of the select options can only be selected once. You can see how it works in this example http://plnkr.co/edit/BBqnTlxobUpiYxfhyJuj?p=preview, where I got the filter from. The filter is called in ng-repeat of <option>

Comment: I call the filter with the currently selected value (`diff`, in my example it's calles `priority`) as in the origin example but  there it is an array and in my case it is a number... I couldn't make out how to change it or why it even is an array in the origin example.

Comment: This looks like the issue/question is larger than the scope of the code you've provided here.

Comment: But I only want the array to be filtered by this given number. It does not have to be like the example filter it was just the only thing I found that did exactly what I wanted.